# react-map-gl Cross-Origin Request does not succeed, not found?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, react-map-gl

I'm setting up a map in react-map-gl however after providing my access token I am getting the following console error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://events.mapbox.com/events/v2?access_token=TOKEN. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

I had installed react-map-gl with

```
npm install --save react-map-gl mapbox-gl
```

Now i look at it, it seems to not be working on any service that uses Mapbox, including the samples page.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I disabled my Adguard DNS and it worked on my project.

I have checked a [few similar errors](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4420#issuecomment-1024167353) and disabling it loads the project